# Postsharp compile-time validation on interface methods

Tags: .net, aop, postsharp

I have an assembly that contains service contracts(assembly name is `Contracts`). I want to implement authorization on those methods using attributes and **PostSharp**.
The authorization attribute looks like this:

```
public class Auth : System.Attribute 
{
    public Auth(String permission){...}
}
```

I want my service contracts to look like this:

```
namespace Contracts
{
    public interface IService
    {
        [Auth("CanCallFoo")]
        void Foo();
    }
}
```

I want to check at compile-time that all the methods from the interfaces in the `Contracts` assembly have an `Auth` attribute.
In order to do this I've created the following aspect:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Interface & MulticastTargets.Method)]
public class EnforceSecurityAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(System.Reflection.MethodBase method)
    {
        var hasSecurityAttribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(x => x is Auth);
        if (!hasSecurityAttribute)
        {
            throw new InvalidAnnotationException(String.Format("Add `Auth` to `{0}`", method.Name));
        }

        return base.CompileTimeValidate(method);
    }
}
```

I apply the aspect using this line of code in AssemblyInfo of `Contracts` assembly:

```
[assembly: EnforceSecurityAspect()]
```

Within the same assembly I also have DTOs, which are used by the services.
The problem I am facing is that **the aspect gets also applied to DTOs**
For example I have a DTO like this

```
public class Client
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
}
```

and at compile-time i get an error that says that I should add `Auth` to the compiler-generated `get_Name` method.
**Q: Is there a way to tell Postsharp that the aspect should be applied only to methods of interfaces?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I wanted to provide an anwser to anyone having this issue as well.

While it may be possible to use specific targets inheriting/implementing a certain interface/class with postsharp i dont't know how.

the solution to this is to create an aspect and target the classes (haven't dont this yet, but im sure its possible). you can then use reflection to validate only the classes that inherit from a certain class/interface using methods available on [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) such as [FindInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx)

use something simmilat to the below code. (Note this is a postsharp Enterprice feature)

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Class)]
public class MulticastTest : MulticastAttribute, IScalarConstraint
{
    public void ValidateCode(object target)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool ValidateConstraint(object target)
    {
        var type = target.GetType();
        Console.Write(type.Name);//Actually do something here
        return true;
    }
}
```