# .NET Standard assembly attribute with DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, .net, validation, custom-attributes, .net-standard

### Background

I'm trying to implement a custom attribute that can be applied to a .NET assembly to indicate an expiry date (the date after which the developers do not support the use of a pre-release version that has been distributed for testing). It has to be written in .NET Standard (2.0).

I know that I can't pass a `DateTime` in as a parameter so I'm passing in a string that conforms to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (YYYY-MM-DD) and then using [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert to a `DateTime`.

The attribute I've got so far is below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class UnstableReleaseExpiryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UnstableReleaseExpiryAttribute(string expiryDate)
    {
        ExpiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
    public DateTime Expiry
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExpiryDate != null && DateTime.TryParse(ExpiryDate, out DateTime expiry))
                return expiry;

            return DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
    }
    public string ExpiryDate { get; }
}
```

This is how I intend to use it:

```
[assembly: UnstableReleaseExpiry("2018-05-24")]
```

### Question

Is there a way to validate the string input using, say, a regex expression, and stop it from being compiled if the date isn't actually parsable? I looked around and thought that inheriting from [`ValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) would be the way to do it, but it doesn't appear to be available in .NET Standard 2.0. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't at this point of time. `ValidationAttribute` is only an "annotation" about what should be the format of a field/property. Other C# code must activate it.

- You could create a code analysis rule to check for this.
- Similar questions: [Is it possible to query custom Attributes in C# during compile time ( not run-time )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753255/is-it-possible-to-query-custom-attributes-in-c-sharp-during-compile-time-not-r), [Postsharp compile-time validation on interface methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521259/postsharp-compile-time-validation-on-interface-methods) . You could use `Fody` instead of `PostSharp` probably
- Simple solution I have used (because handling post-compilation steps is a pain, and code analyzers can be disabled): if you have a unit test project, make a test that uses reflection to find all the usage of the attribute and checks it.